# Does support HP Pavilion 17-f152nr M2 or MSATA?

Tags: laptop, hp-pavilion, msata

I have `HP Pavilion 17-f152nr`.

How can I check has laptop M2 or MSATA without pulling it apart?

Unfortunately I did not find answer on [HP Support](https://support.hp.com/us-en/) website and [Google](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1600&bih=788&ei=J-UyWsSDBYjJ6AToz4moCQ&q=hp%20pavilion%2017-f152nr%20msata&oq=hp%20pavilion%2017-f152nr%20msata&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1448.6484.0.6917.14.11.3.0.0.0.119.1125.6j5.11.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.7.725...0j33i21k1j33i160k1j0i22i30k1.0.klTYapzbTcs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I check if my laptop [HP Pavilion 17-f152nr ] has M2 or MSATA?

Look at the [spec](https://icecat.us/p/hp/k1x73ea/noutbuki-0888793816080-17-f152nr-24749497.html).

It has neither:

> [image]

Source [HP Pavilion 17-f152nr 1.9GHz i3-4030U 17.3" 1600 x 900pixels Black,Silver Notebook](https://icecat.us/p/hp/k1x73ea/noutbuki-0888793816080-17-f152nr-24749497.html)

Comment: I kinda confirmed that with [service manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04427554) - which is found [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-pavilion-17-f100-notebook-pc-series/7234909/model/7485984/manuals) Also useful *if* it had said ports since it shows you how to take apart the machine.